# Yii2 hide action name from url

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to remove action name from url. 'post/view' to 'page' using urlManager but it's not working

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Hide index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Use pretty URLs
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => [
                //'<view:\w+>' => 'post/<alias>',
                //'<alias:view>' => 'post/<alias>',
                'page' => 'post/view',
                ],
        ],
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: How are you creating the url? Post some code, please.

Comment: -http://localhost:8585/yii2basic/wfp/web/post/view?id=PGr1mtIkAE

Comment: So what happens if you try http://localhost:8585/yii2basic/wfp/web/page?id=PGr1mtIkAE

Comment: I get the page, but that not what I want I want the url be like 
 : localhost:8585/yii2basic/wfp/web/post/id=PGr1mtIkAE

Comment: try creating a virtual host and then attempt to use `Yii::$app->urlManager->creteUrl` to generate urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config to include the id:

```
'page/<id>' => 'post/view'
```

Allows you to use urls like this:

```
localhost:8585/yii2basic/wfp/web/page/PGr1mtIkAE
```

You can't really do this:

```
localhost:8585/yii2basic/wfp/web/post/id=PGr1mtIkAE
```